# In Exodus 2:2 why is the baby Moses described as TOV?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, shemot-exodus

In [Exodus 2:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9863/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#v2) what did Moses' mother notice about him that made her name him this? Is it why she hid him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rashi says:](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.1.20?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

> THAT HE WAS GOODLY — When he was born the whole house became filled
>   with light (Sotah 12a).

Ramban says:

> All women love their children, whether they are beautiful or not; and
>   certainly, all the Jewish mothers in Egypt hid their children as long
>   as they could. Consequently, why does the verse need to emphasize that
>   she saw he was good? The explanation is that she saw an unusual
>   goodness about him and the thought entered her mind that a miracle
>   would occur whereby he would be saved. Therefore, she took it to heart
>   and began to think of ways to save him. When she saw she could not
>   hide him any longer, she thought of a new strategy and made him a
>   wicker basket. His sister stationed herself at a distance, so she
>   would not be discovered, to know what would be done with him. All this
>   supports the view of our Sages who said that the entire house became
>   filled with light upon his birth (Shmos Rabbah 1:20, Sotah 12a). It
>   also lends support to their statement (Ibid.) that Miriam had
>   prophesized that her mother would give birth to the savior of the
>   people of Israel.

The Seforno says:

> The word טוב may be understood as meaning the same as “handsome,
>   beautiful,” the same meaning as in Genesis 6,2 כי טובות הנה, “that
>   they were beautiful.” The word describes something unusually handsome,
>   beautiful. Yocheved thought that this was an omen, a sign from the
>   Creator, telling her that a beautiful exterior encloses an equally
>   beautiful personality.

The Chizkuni says:

1. > “and when she saw (realised) that he was good (healthy) etc.” seeing
   >   that Moses was born to his mother after a pregnancy that had lasted
   >   only six months, she noted when examining the baby in detail, that all
   >   of Moses’ fingernails and toe nails were fully developed just like
   >   those of a baby after a nine month pregnancy, she realised that he was
   >   healthy and would survive the critical months ahead of him. She had no
   >   problem hiding him for three months as she had not been due to give
   >   birth during that period. When she was asked about the baby she had
   >   born by her neighbours, she would say that she had already complied
   >   with the kings’ decree and had thrown him into the Nile. A different
   >   interpretation views the word טוב as a hint that Moses had been born
   >   without a foreskin. The custom of reciting the line: הודו לה' כי טוב,
   >   “praise the Lord for He is good,” is recited during the circumcision
   >   ceremony, as a reminder that Moses did not need to be circumcised.

So we have various possibilities:

When he was born the whole house became filled with light.

She saw an unusual goodness about him and the thought entered her mind that a miracle would occur whereby he would be saved. Therefore, she took it to heart and began to think of ways to save him.

The word טוב describes something unusually handsome, beautiful. Yocheved thought that this was an omen, a sign from the Creator, telling her that a beautiful exterior encloses an equally beautiful personality.

All of Moses’ fingernails and toe nails were fully developed just like those of a baby after a nine month pregnancy, she realised that he was healthy and would survive the critical months ahead of him. She had no problem hiding him for three months as she had not been due to give birth during that period.

A different interpretation views the word טוב as a hint that Moses had been born without a foreskin.

Answer (score 5):

Sotah 12a:

> (שמות ב, ב) ותרא אותו כי טוב הוא  תניא ר"מ אומר  טוב שמו ר' יהודה אומר  טוביה שמו רבי נחמיה אומר  הגון לנביאות אחרים אומרים  נולד כשהוא מהול וחכמים אומרים בשעה שנולד משה נתמלא הבית כולו אור כתיב הכא ותרא אותו כי טוב הוא וכתיב התם (בראשית א, ד) וירא אלהים את האור כי טוב
>
> ”And she saw him, that he was ‘tov’ [good]”. It was taught in a Braisa: R’ Meir says, “‘Tov’ was his name.” R’ Yehudah says, “‘Tuviah’ was his name.” R’ Nechemiah says, “He was fitting for prophecy.” Others say, “He was born circumcised.” The Sages say, “When Moshe was born, the house was filled with light. It says here, ‘And she saw him, that it was good,’ and it says there (Bereishis 1:4), ‘And G-d saw the light, that it was good.’”

Besides for R’ Meir and R’ Yehudah’s disagreement about Moshe’s name, it’s possible that none of these opinions are arguing; perhaps it’s because of all of the latter three opinions that Yocheved names him Tov/Tuviah. (Tosfos don’t seem to learn like this, but it’s possible that others do; I haven’t seen anyone else comment one way or another.)